# Fetching Products From other Stores

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

My use case is simple: I want to fetch products that are listed in **other peoples** stores.

I got the following API working, it returns a list of products that I have added to **my own store**:

`https://{{my_store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-01/products.json`

I have contacted a bunch of store owners and they're said they're ok with me wanting to fetch their product details via an API. I want something like:

`https://{{xyz_person's_store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-01/products.json`

Can somebody please tell me if this is possible? I am open to any kind of approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the Shopify Admin API on your Shopify store, it means you probably built an app that is installed on your store.
When you install an app on a Shopify Store, you get an access token that allows Shopify Admin API access **only on this store**

In order to fetch products from multiple stores, you'll need to install your app on each single store.

To do so you may choose to distribute your app on the Shopify App store

Answer (score 0):

If you talked to the merchant of OTHER store, and they agreed it was OK for you to pull products from their store, they can use their Admin to generate an API key that authorizes READ access to their products. You can then use that token in your operations to read their products and install them in your store. You save yourself the hassle then of installing an App in their store, and they can delete your access if they feel like it, when they want.